# HTML 5 Audio lib - How to get the average value of the music table

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have found there a nice and working perfectly fine tutorial to play with music with a web library.

Everything is working fine but I would like to have the "average value" of the music I play. Let me explain that. Currently: music is loaded,

```
function loadSound(url) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

        // When loaded decode the data
        request.onload = function() {

            // decode the data
            context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
                // when the audio is decoded play the sound
                playSound(buffer);
            }, onError);
        }
        request.send();
    }
```

and buffer played. I can easily find the average value of the buffer that way:

```
var getAverage = function(dataArray){
        var total = 0,                               // initialize to 0
            i = 0, length = dataArray.length;
        while(i < length) total += dataArray[i++];   // add all
        return length ? total / length : 0;          // divide (when length !== 0)
    }
```

used there

```
javascriptNode.onaudioprocess = function() {

        // get the average for the first channel
        var array =  new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);

        // clear the current state
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 325);

        // set the fill style
        ctx.fillStyle=gradient;
        drawSpectrum(array);
        var averageVal = getAverage(array);
```

But what about the "global" value and not only the one put in the buffer?

In a word: how to recover the global Uint8Array object from the loaded mp3, and not only the parsed buffer?

Many thanks for you help!

Comment: What do you mean by "global" value?

Comment: Mh, I know that's a tricky one to express. I currently compute the average value of the buffer (as described above). What I would like to do is not the average for the buffer only but for the whole array corresponding to the whole mp3. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recap: You have a program which streams an MP3 file. Periodically you are called back with consecutive chunks of the stream and you are able to compute an average for each individual chunk. You would like to compute the average for the entire stream.

The only way to compute the average is to maintain a running sum over the entire stream and a count of the number of elements to divide it by. I don't know javascript but you would need to store these two values in variables outside of the scope of the function.

```
var getSum = function(dataArray){
    var sum = 0,                               // initialize to 0
    i = 0, length = dataArray.length;
    while(i < length) sum += dataArray[i++];   // add all
    return sum;
}

var sum = 0;
var N = 0;

javascriptNode.onaudioprocess = function() {
    ...
    sum += getSum(array);
    N += array.length;
}
```

Later when the stream finishes you need to compute `average=sum/N`.

An issue you might encounter is that sum can overflow depending on the overall capacity of the sum variable, the size of the samples, and the length of the stream. So first do what is necessary to make sum a `double`. If that is not enough you might have to settle for an approximation like taking an average of averages. It will be pretty close so long as each chunk is close to the same size.

```
var getSum = function(dataArray){
    var sum = 0,                               // initialize to 0
    i = 0, length = dataArray.length;
    while(i < length) sum += dataArray[i++];   // add all
    return sum;
}

var sumOfAverages = 0;
var N = 0;

javascriptNode.onaudioprocess = function() {
    ...
    sum = getSum(array);
    sumOfAverages = sum / array.length;
    N += 1;
}
```

Comment: Ahahah thanks for that this is exactly what I did and was about to post the answer. Many thanks!